# Training Tesseract OCR for ambiguities

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I am pretty new to data scraping and I am facing a minor issue.

I am trying to extract text from a Hindi pdf using `textract` and `Tesseract` OCR. 
Following is the code in Python:

```
import textract

text = textract.parsers.process("test.pdf", encoding='utf_8', method='tesseract', language = 'hin')
```

Now, many of the words from the PDF are correctly extracted. However, there are some things that are messed up. I read the documentation and about how ambiguities can be overridden by using a file `lang.unicharambigs`. However, I need to run `combine_tessdata` in order to actually bring it into effect and override certain trained data.

However, when I try to run the command I get the following:

```
 -bash: combine_tessdata: command not found
```

I have installed `tesseract` from the source and I can't seem to understand why this is happening. Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tesseract training executables are built separately.

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling

Comment: Okay that makes sense. However, the problem that I am facing now is how do I install these libraries on a mac OSX? `libicu-dev 
libpango1.0-dev
libcairo2-dev `